# How to use blending in libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

How to adapt this c# code for libgdx java?

```
SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Texture, maxBlend);

private static readonly BlendState maxBlend = new BlendState() {
    AlphaBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Max,
    ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Max,
    AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.One,
    AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One,
    ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.One,
    ColorSourceBlend = Blend.One
};
```

I found it there:
[article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-generate-shockingly-good-2d-lightning-effects--gamedev-2681)

tried this code, but it isn't work correctly:

```
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE);
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_COLOR, GL20.GL_ONE);
```

And this:

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(Gdx.gl20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(Gdx.gl20.GL_ONE, Gdx.gl20.GL_ONE);
Gdx.gl.glEnable(Gdx.gl20.GL_BLEND_COLOR);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(Gdx.gl20.GL_ONE, Gdx.gl20.GL_ONE);
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `batch.setBlendFunction()` method takes the parameters for the SRC and DST parameters of the blend function, not the channel and parameter like you're doing.

And by default, OpenGL changes both RGB and alpha to the same values simultaneously. So your call should be:

```
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);
```

To use the MAX blend equation, you must be using GL 3.0 because OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support it. Right after `batch.begin()` put:

```
Gdx.gl30.glBlendEquation(GL30.GL_MAX);
```

To "clean up" after your changes, put this right after `batch.end()` so other stuff will be drawn as expected:

```
Gdx.gl30.glBlendEquation(GL20.GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

Answer (score -3):

1. You can create wrapper libraries or Java Byte Code that uses C# methods. You should be able to autogen and export your new wrapper library using VisualStudio, as outlined here: [Wrap C# Libraries for Java](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java)
2. Why insist on libgdx? You can use OpenGL in Java: [Java Binding for the OpenGL Library](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/)

Comment: 2 horrible suggestions